# How can I solve$\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{n}{2}\left( \dfrac{1}{2^n} + \dfrac{1}{3^n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{n}{2}\left( \dfrac{1}{2^n} + \dfrac{1}{3^n}\right)$

I can't get much out of trying to solve it. It's told that it can be written as $\dfrac{a}{b}$, where a and b are positive integers.

Comment: A reminder to please check that the tags you set for your question actually apply to your question.  [Measure Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29) is an entirely different topic than what your question is about and should not have been the tag for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x},$$,
taking the derivative of both sides yields
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}.$$
But,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n.$$

Hence,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n=\frac1{(1-x)^2}-\frac1{1-x}.$$

Letting
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$$
you are looking to find the value of 
$$\frac12\left[f\left(\frac12\right)+f\left(\frac13\right)\right].$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Derivate 
$$\frac{1}{1-x}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

What do you get when you plug in $x=\frac{1}{2}$? What about $x=\frac{1}{3}$?